# What would be a good consent description for the openid scope?

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, openid-connect, scopes

When signing in a user using OpenID, typically a consent screen is shown listing the requested scopes and a short description, e.g.:

- `profile`: Allow client X  ... to access your profile data
- `email`: Allow client X ... to access your email address
- ...

What would be the description for the `openid` scope in this case?
Or should it not even be shown on the consent page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually something like this, since after authentication, one or more user identifiers are issued to access tokens sent to resource servers:

- Allow client X ... to access your account ID